# C# в visual studio code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Итак, значит пытаюсь я "завести" C# на vscode и получаю какую-то тарабарщину в результате, пробовал искать сам как решить такую проблему но как-то не удалось поэтому пишу здесь. Скриншот прилагаю
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: _тарабарщину_ - это называется "кириллица отображается в неправильной кодировке". По ключевому слову "тарабарщина" вы вряд-ли смогли бы что-то толковое найти про VS Code.

Comment: @aepot я искал cryptic symbols in vscode console и не смог найти решение своей проблемы. А даже если и искать неверное отображение кириллицы всё равно не смог найти, и к тому же неясно почему я не вижу hello в консоли, оно же не на русском написано

Comment: "invalid encoding cyrillic in visual studio code output" https://stackoverflow.com/a/73084444/12888024

Comment: @aepot сделал как в вопросе, теперь ловлю ошибку уже такую CommandNotFoundException, посмотрел кажется связано с переменными среды, ищу как добавить в PATH, при установке я видимо этого не сделал теперь сижу мучаюсь, подскажите если знаете как пожалуйста

Comment: Думаю может всё-таки лучше чтобы вы увидели что именно написано, я взял просто название ошибки, а вот что мне пишет студия
scriptcs : Имя "scriptcs" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:1
+ scriptcs "f:\vscode C#\Program.cs"
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (scriptcs:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Решил попробовать справиться с проблемой радикально, но переустановка студии не сработала, во время установки галочка с переменными среды установлена и никакого результата, по-прежнему вылетает ошибка commandNotFound

Comment: Я используб VS 2022, так что вряд-ли чем-то смогу помочь.